# failure to upload multiple images using move_upload_file

Tags: php, file, upload

I have a form, upon submission, it will create a new directory, all images submitted along with the form will be upload in the said directory.

this is the shortened code.

```
    mkdir('uploads/'.$name, 0777, true); //create directory

    $count = count($_FILES['images']['tmp_name']); //count all uploaded files
    for ($i=0; $i<$count; $i++) 
    { 

    //formatting
    $file     = $_FILES['images']['name'][$i];
    $filename = strtolower($file);
    $random   = rand(0, 999); //Random number to be added to name.
    $newfile  = $random.$filename; //new file name


    //upload
    if (move_uploaded_file($newfile, "uploads/".$name."/".$newfile)) 
    {
     echo "uploaded";
    } else {
     echo " failed";
    }

    }
```

if i echo the directory `echo "upload to =" . $teamdir."/".$newfile;`

it shows the correct path `/uploads/john/567banner_0.jpg`

but the image aren't being uploaded.

Comment: on which os you are working? if its linux, give permissions to the folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bool move_uploaded_file ( string $filename , string $destination )
```

Your first parameter has to be the source so you have to give it the temp name assigned
by php.

In your case : $_FILES['images']['tmp_name'][$i]

Comment: thank you so much! i guess the `$filename` parameter was too vague for me, didn't thought that this should be the temp name. anyway. thanks for you help. you saved me :)

Answer (score 1):

I feel you should add

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/path/to/uploads/
```

in image destination path